# packages libgtest-dev, googletest, google-mock

Tags: apt, package-management

I found that I have the packages libgtest-dev, googletest and google-mock installed.
I do not know what this is and I cannot remember that I installed this.
In /var/log/apt/history* is nothing.

Is it safe to uninstall?

Comment: No it's not, some package you installed might have installed to assist it so please don't!

Comment: Do `dpkg-query -S <name_of_package>` to know who owns them!